# Can a user see the source of a js call in an html 5 app for iphone or android?

Tags: android, ios, html

If I create a html 5 application for a phone (using phonegap or Icenium) that calls a webservice which needs a username/password, can a person look at the code somehow or is the JavaScript compiled away or obstructed  in some manner?
Assume in this case that the url is in a javascript file with username and password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Phonegap nor Icenium (both based on Apache Cordova) obfuscate or compile the JavaScript code of your app.

You can take any Cordova app for iOS or Android and simply unzip the .ipa or .apk package to reveal the HTML, CSS and JavaScript code that powers the app.

Answer (score 2):

If its a regular user, then most-likely not. 
But if you are asking this question because you want to prevent someone that is skilled want needs to see your app for code. Then the answer is:

**Nothing is safe in your clients device.** Not sqlite database, not built-int storage , and not source code( weather its compiled or not);